# Using SELECT to call a function in a jdbc migration

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgis, clojure

I'm looking to set up some Postgres/PostGIS migrations with clojure/jdbc.

running side-effect functions with `SELECT` is proving to be an issue, with most migration libs eventually throwing the `A result was returned when none was expected` error, because at some point they use `clojure.java.jdbc/execute!` or `clojure.java.jdbc/db-do-commands`, which seems understandable, but frustrating when you need to call a function that's critical to the migration.

The [PostGIS's docs encourage](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Create_Spatial_Table) using `SELECT` statement to create a spatial column:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('parks', 'park_geom', 128, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 2 );
```

Has anyone run into this or found an appropriate workaround for using functions in a clojure/jdbc and Postgres migration?

---

related tidbits:

- [this](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column) description for manually registering a spatial column looks promising but seems remarkably heavy-handed for something that already has a supporting function
- there's also `PL/PgSQL`'s [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html) statement that I stumbled across but it seems like I'm grasping at straws at that point, despite it [looking promising](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT)
- `clojure.java.jdbc/execute!` docs give a [specific heads-up](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/execute!) about only using "general (non-select) SQL operation[s]"

Comment: That seems a bug with the clojure tool. I guess it runs all migration statements using `Statement.executeUpdate()` rather than `Statement.execute()`. Can you wrap the call into a `do` block and use `perform` inside the `do` block? But this should rather be fixed in clojure

Comment: I tried this: `(execute! db-spec ["DO $$ PERFORM AddGeometryColumn('parks', 'park_geom', 128, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 2 ); $$;"])` and got a `syntax error at or near "PERFORM"`, though I'm not a postgres aficionado, so perhaps there's a glaring error there for someone more experienced. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this by using the `DO` command like so:

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN
    PERFORM AddGeometryColumn('parks', 'park_geom', 128, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 2 );
END;
$$
```

Note the `BEGIN` and `END` are necessary as it has to be a valid plpgsql block.